# TypeScript: Infer type of <this> in Object extension method

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, typescript-generics

I am trying to implement something similiar to the [let scope function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html#let) of kotlin in TypeScript.

My current approach is to use declaration merging with the `Object` interface. Which generally works but I'm lacking the type information of the argument for the inner method (See example below).

Is there a way to infer the type of the Object where the function was called on?

```
interface Object {
  let: <S>(block: <T = this>(thisVal: T) => S) => S | null
}

Object.prototype.let = function <T, S>(block: (thisVal: T) => S): S | null {
  return this != null ? block(this as T) : null
}

const a = {foo: 42}
// don't want to write this -> 'a.let<typeof a>(it => console.log(it.foo));'
a.let(it => console.log(it.foo)); // type of 'it' is T = Object
```

[Try here on TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPICMBWEFmQbwChlkAbCMALmQB4BlAPgAp1SB7BAa2poBVkAvMjAALYAGdmoiQDU4parwCUghsjoqBausgA+yEAFdSpQgF9ChDNlwA6AA5Q2YZwE97EW+TxCYhkLjAbCC0vAA06sysHNzITNLicgrIyqrqStQ6+kYmBMTIUBSGUCEJyACEQjmkyAD8yNFc8WLiyHCtqdTV5pYIweJ4cIIEMGxs1AAsAEwWAPSzbV4UNGDuEGwwbczAPmp9IOJs5F5sAOZMO7ajbEpKANyEcEtgF7vI+4fH7OeX17cPQA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by adding a `this` parameter to the `let` function and capture `this` from the `let` call:

```
interface Object {
  let: <S, T>(this: T,  block: (thisVal: T) => S) => S | null
}

Object.prototype.let = function <S, T>(this: T,  block: (thisVal: T) => S): S | null {
  return this != null ? block(this as T) : null
}

const a = {foo: 42}
a.let(it => console.log(it.foo));
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPICMBWEFmQbwChlkAbCMALmQB4BlAGmQBUA+ACjAAtgBna5k2TpSAewQBrapx68AanFICAlMgC8rZHVUatyAD7IQAV1KlCAX0KEM2XADoADlFFhXAT0cR75PGuQwxiC4wKIgtIwsHNx8AkIi4lLIMnwKSiw6mtrUdAZGpqQExMhQFMZQ4TG8yACE-iZmyAD8wmKSKdVw1cyq1A3mVoQIYbx4cOoEMKKi1AAsAExWcD4U7MB+msMgvKLkPqIA5mtg9lOiysoA3IRAA)